# Show Month Name and year in Datatable Date Column

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable

In my datatable I have two date columns which are displaying data like Mar, 1, 2016. I would like to remove the Day and just want to display like Mar, 2016.

```js
$('#bo_test_table').dataTable({
   "scrollY": 800,
   "scrollCollapse": true,
   "bServerSide" : true,
   "searching": false,
   "sAjaxSource" : "<Servlet URL>",
   "bProcessing" : true,
   "sPaginationType" : "full_numbers",
   "bJQueryUI" : true,
   "lengthMenu" : [ 25, 50, 100 ],
   "responsive": true,
   "bAutoWidth": true, 
   "oLanguage" : {
    "sProcessing" : "Loading. Please wait..."
   },
   "aoColumns": [
    { "mDataProp": "boCountryName" , "defaultContent": "<i>Not Available</i>"},
    { "mDataProp": "boSupplierName" , "defaultContent": "<i>Not Available</i>"},
    { "mDataProp": "boProduct" , "defaultContent": "<i>Not Available</i>"},
    { "mDataProp": "boUsageMonth" , "defaultContent": "<i>Not Available</i>"},
    { "mDataProp": "boUsageValue" , "defaultContent": "<i>Not Available</i>"},
    { "mDataProp": "boCurrDate" , "defaultContent": "<i>Not Available</i>"},
    { "mDataProp": "boCurrency" , "defaultContent": "<i>Not Available</i>"},
                   ],
   "aoColumnDefs": [ 
    { 
     "aTargets": [4,5,6], 
     "orderable": false 
    },
    { 
     "aTargets": [3,5], 
     "stype": "date", 
     "fnRender": function(data) {
      if(data != null) {
       var javascriptDate = new Date(data);
       javascriptDate = javascriptDate.getMonth() + 1 + "/" + javascriptDate.getFullYear();
       return "<div class='date'>"+javascriptDate+"<div>";
      }
     }
    }
   ]
  });
```

I found the above solution in the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28733613/format-json-date-to-mm-dd-yy-format-before-displaying-in-a-jquery-datatable). But it is showing date as 03/2016 format.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a lot in the front end I actually solved the problem in the backend. Modified the actual SQL script `to_char(USAGE_MONTH,'MON-YYYY') as USAGE_MONTH`. This solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can define an array which returns name of month

```
    var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
       "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
     ];
    months [javascriptDate.getMonth()+1]
```

Comment: Could you plz show me how to achieve this using the fnRender(). The return statement doesn't work

Comment: You can define an array above the your code or inside fnRender.

Comment: "fnRender": function(data) {
      if(data != null) {
            var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May",  "June",
       "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
     ];
       var javascriptDate = new Date(data);
       javascriptDate =  months [javascriptDate.getMonth()+1] + "/" + javascriptDate.getFullYear();
       return "<div class='date'>"+javascriptDate+"<div>";
      }
     }