# How to set Date format in Datatable in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript, i am getting date from query, but i want change another formate

```
$('#example1').DataTable({
         "ajax": {
            "url": "/txnlist/data",
            "data": {"date":[[${date}]]},
            "dataSrc": ""
        },

        "columns": [
            { "data": "id" },
            { "data": "AccountNumber" },
            { "data": "TransactionDate"} // date:032716
        ],
});
```

here i am getting date `mmddyy`,but i want `yyyy-dd-mm`. How to change it?

Comment: maybe this: https://datatables.net/reference/option/formatNumber

Comment: https://www.google.hu/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28733613/format-json-date-to-mm-dd-yy-format-before-displaying-in-a-jquery-datatable&ved=0ahUKEwipq5ih27zUAhUHIJoKHR1tCxoQFggaMAA&usg=AFQjCNEyJhIEylIfGloRL8_CWIj48LP6fw&sig2=3hJhXgGRkXUxlH2-WTdCnw

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28733613/format-json-date-to-mm-dd-yy-format-before-displaying-in-a-jquery-datatable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code as an example:

```
var yourDate = '032716'; //mmddyy
// keep in mind that 16 is ambiguous as it could be either 1916 or 2016 so parse it properly
var year = '20' + yourDate.substring(4, 6);
var month = yourDate.substring(0, 2);
var day = yourDate.substring(2, 4);
// pass params as yy mm dd
var dateObj = new Date(year, month, day);

var parsedDateObj = dateObj.getFullYear() + '-' + month + '-' + day; // yyyy-dd-mm
console.log(parsedDateObj); // output: 2016-03-27
```

Try it online on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1tLd6zdh/2/).

Alternatively if you don't mind using a library for that you could use [moment js](https://momentjs.com/) and format it like this:

```
moment(dateObj).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Comment: "TypeError: yourDate.substring is not a function" i am getting

Comment: @Durga Is your date 032716 an integer or a string? If it is an integer make sure that you pass it as a string.

Comment: Finally i am getting output but `209-32-91` my original date is `032917`

Comment: @Durga make sure to pass the correct value as string to 'yourDate' variable. Add a console.log and check if the value you pass is correct, casting to string as 032716.toString() will return "13774" which is not the value you want. Check the link with the online example I have added.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, you saved my day

Answer (score 1):

You are a beginner so think it simple. if you go with custom functions you will get confused.

try to use `moment.js` a timezone js library.

check my answer how i did using `moment.js`

for your easy understand will split it further,

```js
my_date_format = "032716" // your date in MM(Month)DD(date)YY(2 digit year format)
my_date = moment(my_date_format, "MM-DD-YY") // getting moment date based on your format. here, date is your input date and exisitng format you have
new_date = my_date.format("YYYY-MM-DD") // date you want to format  
console.log(new_date)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.1/moment.js"></script>
<div id="example1"></div>
```